# Obtener texto dentro de etiquetas comentadas usando BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estoy haciendo un scraping a un documento HTML usando BeautifulSoup4. Pero me vi en la obligación de obtener Texto comentado. Si quiero obtener texto comentado como este :

```
<!-- este es el texto -->
```

Eso se puede obtener (obviando las demás declaraciones) así:

```
texto = soup.find_all(string = lambda text:isinstance(text,Comment))
```

Pero yo quiero obtener el texto dentro de una etiqueta comentada de esta forma:

```
<!-- <span>texto que quiero</span> -->
```

Hay alguna forma de que se pueda hacer? El codigo en python que coloque me devuelve un objeto de la librería bs4, no un string, por lo tanto no conozco la manera de convertirlo a string y hacer un replace, Esto como último recurso, pues me gustaría hacer casi todo usando las funcionalidades de bs4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una vez has encontrado el comentario, puedes convertirlo a cadena con `str()`.

En tu caso, la cadena resultante en el fondo es otro documento html, por lo que perfectamente puedes volver a usar BeautifulSoup sobre él, para analizarlo y buscar dentro el tag `<span>` o lo que sea.

Demostración de la idea:

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element

>>> doc = """
<html><head><title>Ejemplo</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>Ejemplo</b></p>

<!-- <span>texto que quiero</span> -->

<p>Texto adicional de relleno que no viene al caso.</p>

<p class="story">...</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
>>> comentarios = soup.find_all(string = lambda text: isinstance(text, element.Comment))
>>> primer_comentario = str(comentarios[0])
>>> texto = BeautifulSoup(primer_comentario).span.contents[0]
>>> texto
```

---

```
'texto que quiero'
```